# Evergreen K&R ex. 1-21 entab

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

a hobbyist here. I tried my best before coming here, and my solution "kind of works", but not always, and I find especially hard to debug this "simple" problem.

"Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing. Use the same tab stops, say every n columns. Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?"

To help to understand my code easier here is a short explanation, so hopefully someone can understand what I am trying to do.

0. position is set/incremented by tabs and any other nonspace characters, spaces do not increment it. I will need both pos and space_count for a check at step 3.
1. check if input is space or something else, if it is space then I increment space_count, if it isn't than do step 2-3-4:
2. if not space is the input, first I check if I have enough spaces to convert them to tabs, so if I have input starting with 17 spaces for instance and a tab is 8 spaces, print two tabs, decrement space_count to 1, and set position to second tab stop at col 16.
3. after this I check if the sum of remaining spaces and current position reaches or exceeds the next tab stop, if yes, print one tab, decrement space_count to the amount it exceeds the current tab stop.
4. after all these I use if - else if - else branching to process what happens if tab, newline or any other nonspace char is the input. Since these are fine to print immediately unlike space, I print them.
   (so continuing the above example, I have 2 tabs, pos=16, space_counter = 1, next tab stop at 24. If I press letter A, print the spaces (1 in this case), print A, set position to 18. Now if I were to put more than 5 spaces, step 3 branch would execute as 18 + 6 = 24, so we reached next tab stop).

For most input I tested it works I guess, but I have different outcomes if input contains:
"5 spaces, A, 44 spaces, 2 tabs, 3 spaces, A" (not literally, so it starts like      `A`).
If I set TAB_INC to 8, and I check it in notepad, it doesn't have the same spacing (1 tab is missing), so the result is not good.
If I set TAB_INC to 4, and I check it in sublime text, everything is fine if I copy the source+result there... So besides unable to debug it, I can't even get same results with different text editors.

My question is, why or when this logic/code breaks?

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAB_INC 4

static int get_tab_stop(int pos) {
    return ((pos / TAB_INC) + 1) * TAB_INC;
}

static void init(void) {
    int c, pos, space_count;
    c = pos = space_count = 0;

    while (EOF != (c = getchar())) {
        if (' ' == c)
            ++space_count;
        else {
            while (TAB_INC <= space_count) {
                space_count -= TAB_INC;
                pos = get_tab_stop(pos);
                putchar('\t');
            }
            if (pos + space_count >= get_tab_stop(pos)) {
                space_count -= get_tab_stop(pos) - pos;
                pos = get_tab_stop(pos);
                putchar('\t');
            }
            if ('\t' == c) {
                space_count = 0;
                pos = get_tab_stop(pos);
            }
            else if ('\n' == c)
                pos = space_count = 0;
            else {
                pos = pos + space_count + 1;
                while (space_count) {
                    putchar(' ');
                    --space_count;
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example input and the corresponding actual and expected output for both good and bad cases. To allow distinguishing tabs from spaces in the output you could replace tabs with two characters `\t`. Maybe show both the normal and the modified variant.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the problems, step 2 was totally unneccesary and caused problems on its own, step 3 needed rework. Anyway I leave my code here, it might be useful for anyone tackling this in the future.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAB_INC 8

static int get_tab_stop(int pos) {
    return ((pos / TAB_INC) + 1) * TAB_INC;
}

static void init(void) {
    int c, pos, eval_ts, space_count;
    c = pos = eval_ts = space_count = 0;

    while (EOF != (c = getchar())) {
        if (' ' == c)
            ++space_count;
        else {
            while (pos + space_count >= (eval_ts = get_tab_stop(pos))) {
                space_count -= eval_ts - pos;
                pos = eval_ts;
                putchar('\t');
            }
            if ('\t' == c) {
                space_count = 0;
                pos = get_tab_stop(pos);
            }
            else if ('\n' == c)
                pos = space_count = 0;
            else {
                pos = pos + space_count + 1;
                while (space_count) {
                    putchar(' ');
                    --space_count;
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    init();
    return 0;
}
```